# Create cookie on login

Tags: cookies

What is the latest and best way to set a cookie upon login? What I mean is:
if a user succesfully logins, then a session cookie **user-is-logged-in = 1** is set. When the user logs out, this is removed.

I see this https://www.drupal.org/project/logincookie but its very old and doesn't look supported..
I see this but https://www.drupal.org/node/2160739 but it starts with a requirement with Varnish which I don't have..

I am using Drupal version 7.43.

As you know session cookies set by Drupal don't do the trick, as anonymous users are also set a cookie and from a browser's perspective, they are not differentiable.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Added hopefully more details above. this has nothing to do with the Cookie law, i'm just wondering what is the state of the art for setting a cookie based on a login action, if I need to code or add a module or use the regular functionalities. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just write the code yourself in a custom module. What you want is pretty simple.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_login().
 */
function HOOK_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  setcookie('user-is-logged-in', '1', 0, '/');
}

/**
 * Implements hook_user_logout().
 */
function HOOK_user_logout($account) {
  // Set cookie in the past and then remove it.
  setcookie('user-is-logged-in', '', REQUEST_TIME - 3600, '/');
  unset($_COOKIE['user-is-logged-in']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I followed https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7 and it looks like I basically create a .module file with your code; a .info with some sample description and it's all set -- do i miss anything? Thanks a lot!

Comment: mmmm.. it doesn't work :) trying to find the issue.. I load the module fine, the code is executed (if I insert syntax errors I break the site), but i don't see my cookie :(

Comment: @JoeSlav You need to replace HOOK with the module name, that's how hooks work

Comment: thanks a lot, that was a stupid RTFM mistake on my part :) for completeness, the unset call didn't work -- I had to use a seetcookie with expire date in the past to get the cookie unset. cheers and thanks again

Comment: @JoeSlav Great, updated the answer with the complete solution